# how to create folders on a new linux partition using php

Tags: php, linux

I created a new partition in linux, and mounted it in eg / dev / test.
Using php, how can I create new folders within that partition?

I imagined using this form:

```
mkdir('/dev/test/newFolder', 0777);
```

this would create a folder inside the partition?

and I could give write permission to this folder only to create, and to reading all the rest?

I apologize if the question is really basic, but not know much about linux.

Comment: well one thing you can also do is to try if it works. And there is the manual as well: http://php.net/mkdir - looks like the second parameter is superfluous.

Comment: with so minor understanding about that, be careful when creating partitions... ;) ...

Comment: yes, will not be me creating the partition. precisely why I can not test now, since it has not been created yet.

Comment: partions itself live in `/dev/`.. E.g. `/dev/sda1` might be the first partition on the first physical hard drive. Just having the partition you cannot do much with it. You'll create a filesystem on it.. like `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda1`... Then when you have a filesystem you can mount it, usually to an empty existing folder. like `mount /dev/sda1 /data` ... Then you can store files and create folders in `/data/...` .. (!!! don't do anything that you don't fully understand. You may destroy existing data. you have been warned !!! )

Comment: @samuel_R No problem ;)... Will give post my comment as an answer. just to prevent the question from being an unanswered zombie ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitions on Linux are special block devices and live in `/dev/`.. E.g. `/dev/sda1` might be the first partition on the first physical hard drive. Just having the partition you cannot do much with it. You'll create a file system on it. like:

```
mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda1
```

This will create an ext3 file system on the partition `/dev/sda1`.

Then when you have a file system you can mount it, usually to an empty existing folder. like:

```
mkdir /data
mount /dev/sda1 /data
```

It will mount the file system on partition `/dev/sda1` into the existing, empty folder `/data`. Now you can store files and create folders in `/data/...`.

**(!!! don't do anything that you don't fully understand. You may destroy existing data. you have been warned !!!)**